# Что я делаю не так с фокусом?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, activity

[image: Вот Картинка]

Вот что я сделал: http://pastebin.com/a3rX0jjM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ff14a33a"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ff2929a3"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```